# sql sum column in having clause is not summing quarterly values

Tags: sql

i would like to sum (purchase_prd) which is quarterly for customerID where purchase value is >0 and <=500. I have same customer ids in multiple purchase_prd, and would also like to see how many records show for their customerID....how do I query this?
I have the following

```
select purchase_prd, count(*), customerID, sum(purchase_value)
from table a
where purcahse_prd between 201700 and 201712 /*data is quarterly, so 201700, 201703, 201706,201709, 201712*/
group by customerid, purchase_value
having purchase_value >0 and purchase_value<=500
```

my results show customerids in multiple quarters and the sums of purchase_value exceeds 500, each quarter is separate and not extracting the total of purchase_value for the entire year with the criteria of purchase_value >0 and <=500

my results are:

```
purchase_prd            customer ID         purchase_value
201700                          714              776
201703                           714              120
201706                           714              50
201709                            714             20
201712                           714              100
```

I'd like 2017 summed for customerID 714 and selected if sum of purchase_value is >0-<=500

Comment: sample data and desired output would be helpful. Also tag the database name

Comment: my results are:

Comment: Please clarify the question.  It is really hard to follow what you want to accomplish.  Also tag with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
select customerID, purchase_prd, count(*), sum(purchase_value)
from table a
where purchase_prd between 201700 and 201712 /*data is quarterly, so 201700, 201703, 201706,201709, 201712*/
group by customerid, purchase_prd
having sum(purchase_value) > 0 and sum(purchase_value) <= 500
```

Comment: Might want to keep `purchase_prd` in the SELECT even though you correctly put it in the group by ... :)

Comment: the above query doesn't work, doesn't give me counts of customerID with sum purchase_value >0-<=500 for the yearly or 'annualized' 2017

Comment: what if you add count(distinct customer_id)  in the above query??